# Why does interface A hide property from interface B

Tags: c#, interface, get, set

See the code below. Visual Studio 2017 tells me that IGetSet.Value hides property IGet.Value and I should add the `new` keyword if this is intended. I understand the concept of hiding a property with respect to classes, but when it comes to interfaces, I do not see the point of the message. Whether I add the `new` keyword or not doesn't differ in behavior of course.

I want this stacking of the 2 interfaces because I want objects, that implement the read-write interface, to be usable in methods that are only allowed to get the value.

Now my questions are:

1. Is this the way to achieve what I want? I see the message of 'hiding' properties as a signal saying 'You are doing something here you probably don't want to, try to solve it differently'.
2. How can one interface hide the property of another? Doesn't it depend on the implementation of the interfaces? So why the message?

   ```
   public interface IGetSet : IGet
   {
       new string Value { get; set; }
   }

   public interface IGet
   {
       string Value { get; }
   }

   public class Tester : IGetSet
   {
       public string Value { get; set; }
   }

   [Test]
   public void InterfaceTest()
   {
       IGetSet tester = new Tester();
       tester.Value = "My Value";
       IGet getteronly = tester;
       var value = getteronly.Value;
   }
   ```

If I try to solve it with the code below I get this compile error 'CS0229 Ambiguity between 'IGet.Value' and 'ISet.Value''

```
public interface ISet
{
    string Value { set; }
}

public interface IGet
{
    string Value { get; }
}

public interface IGetSet : IGet, ISet
{

}
```

Comment: @Evk3 This only happens when interface is implemented implicitely and the property is being used in code. The line of usage causes the compile error. Thanks for pointing that out. When the property isn't used in code, though the interface is implemented, the code compiles indeed. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this the way to achieve what I want?

Yes.

> I see the message of 'hiding' properties as a signal saying 'You are doing something here you probably don't want to, try to solve it differently'.

No, it means you have to assess if this was intentional. *Did you really intend to create a second definition of the property which overrules the first one?* Yes, you do in this case, but sometimes you wouldn't. So that is why there is a warning asking you to explicitly tell what you want.

As a side note, you could actually end up with a different implementation of both properties when you use explicit interface implementation:

```
public class Tester : IGetSet
{
    string IGet.Value { get { return "A"; } }

    string IGetSet.Value { get { return "B"; } set { } }
}
```

See there is a catch to the warning?

Comment: With repsect to explicit interfaces. IGet.Value is not visible if you address object through the interface IGetSet. So I would say there is no hiding there. And if you have an instance of Tester, you wouldn't see any Value property because of the explicit implementation. So I still disagree with the message saying a property is being hidden.

Comment: There is hiding: you don't see the `get` property right? You are replacing the definition of `Value` in your interface.

Comment: Yes, I see now! What a warm feeling, the light, I embrace the light of the lord! Just having some fun here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If both interfaces have the same properties you have to implement them Explicitly

```
public interface ISet
{
    string Value { set; }
}

public interface IGet
{
    string Value { get; }
}

public class GetSetClass : IGet, ISet
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    string IGet.Value // Explicitly implementation
    {
        get { return Value; }
    }

    string ISet.Value // Explicitly implementation
    {
        set { Value = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, you don't if you want to actually override the property in the interface definition. That is what the first code sample does. The second one is unnecessary and will bring more evil than it fixes in my opinion.

Comment: @PablonotPicasso This is not what I am after because it requires unnecesary code in my opinion to achieve the read-only restriction.